# How to load each libraries/sources according to the route and role in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I have an Angular website, I used that for my website panel, there are some different roles in the panel, some admin roles and some different kind of users and I could handle that and limit different users and route/views by their roles.

**What is the problem?** I bundled all of my needed `*.js` files to one file named **`bundle.js`** and it is working well, but the problem is the file is heavy and it is hard to debug the program just by one file! `bundle.js` is more than 2 mb and I really need to change it.

For example, I have a role which used `d3` which is a heavy size library and just in one route. So, Why should I add that to `bundle.js` when just some kind of users may need it.

**Questions:**

Is there any way, I can have the single page application but still each view/route include its own external javaScripts?

Is bundling files harmful? Is there any real project that bundled all files in one js file?

Comment: 2 mb isn't large, as for me. In my current project 4.7mb of 2 bundles: 3rdparty libs, and project's code

Comment: @Ivan I think he is right, 2 mb is a kind of large file for js! it is hard to debug either

Comment: @Kermani I'm using webpack with dev and prod environments. dev environment doesn't producing any bundles, so its easy to debug, and no need to wait until build finished every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is realy broad as it highly depends on how you implemented your roles and how you organized your code.

For the problem of loading lazily your modules depending on the user and his role, you could take a look at the [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs) library that looks like doing this job (loading modules lazily).

You could also make several bundles for your app (one for each role) an use a server-side script to load the needed one.

Is bundling harmful ?

As you stated bundling can be a problem, if you have many kind of different users, or if you don't know where the user will go after the first page (an app with hundreds of screen, for example).

However you should always bundle because it is more network friendly to load a single big file than hundreds of small ones.

The fact is you have to bundle wisely and make one bundle for each page or group of pages, or user role, etc. Everything depends on how the app works...

So depending on your needs you should make several bundles, whatever happen, let's say a common-one where you store your common functions, modules, routing etc. and others depending on the role or the page you want to display.

Comment: I agree with @n00d13 (such a hard name), but I think bundling files is hard for debugging, if one function has a problem, that could be hard to debug and find it in a large file, as he said over 2 MB

Comment: It's not if you use source-maps